# Howto set my IServiceLocator implementation as ServiceLocator.Current?

Tags: .net, prism, ioc-container, ninject, iservicelocator

I'm working on replacing Unity with Ninject in the Prism framework. This requires me to implement a Ninject specific IServiceLocator. From what I've understood I can inherit the ServiceLocatorImplBase instead, so that's what I do. Now how can I set this to be the Current ServiceLocator? I need this in order to have e.g. the RegionManager get it when it creates regions, and calls:

```
IServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocator.Current;
```

This is a static property, but it doesn't have a setter.. There is a function:

```
void ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(ServiceLocatorProvider newProvider);
```

..but the argument doesn't match my ServiceLocatorImplBase. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ServiceLocatorProvider` is a delegate, you can do this:

```
var container = NInjectServiceLocator(); // your ServiceLocatorImplBase impl.

ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => container);
```

Comment: If you want to know what's the advantage for the `SetLocatorProvider` method over a `Current` setter method, read this discussion: http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=50463.